# Progress ABL format decimal number without leading characters

Tags: csv, number-formatting, progress-4gl, openedge

I just want to format a decimal number for output to a simple CSV formatted file.
I feel like I'm stupid, but I can't find a way to do it without leading zeroes or spaces, of course I can simply trim the leading spaces, but there has to be a proper way to just format like I that, isn't there?

Example

```
define variable test as decimal.
define variable testString as character.
test = 12.3456.
testString = string(test, '>>>>>9.99').
message '"' + testString + '"' view-as alert-box. /* "    12.35" */
```

I tried using `>>>>>9.99` and `zzzzz9.99` for the number format, but both format the string with leading spaces. I actually have no idea what the difference is between using `>` and `z`.

Comment: I don't think there is any way. Progress is rather "text based" and assumes that in order to line your formatted numbers up, you have to have the right amount of leading spaces etc. Format your number and trim it. If you don't care about the format and just want the data, if you don't supply a format I don't think you get any leading or trailing spaces, but you equally can't set the number of decimal places to show etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SUBSTITUTE() function will do what you describe wanting:

```
define variable c as character no-undo.
c = substitute( "&1", 1.23 ).
display "[" + c + "]".
```

(Toss in a TRUNCATE( 1.2345, 2 ) if you really only want 2 decimal places.)

Actually, this also works:

```
string( truncate( 1.2345, 2 )).
```

If you are creating a CSV file you might want to think about using EXPORT.  EXPORT format removes leading spaces and omits decorations like ",".  The SUBSTITUTE() function basically uses EXPORT format to make its substitutions.  The STRING() function uses EXPORT format when no other format is specified.

Comment: Thanks that works for me, I need only 2 decimal places so that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `EXPORT` statement will format your data for you. Here is an example:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE test AS DECIMAL NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE testRound AS DECIMAL NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE testString AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

test = 12.3456.
testRound = ROUND(test, 2).
testString = STRING(test).

OUTPUT TO VALUE("test.csv").
EXPORT DELIMITER "," test testRound testString.
OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

Here is the output:

```
12.3456,12.35,"12.3456"
```

The `EXPORT` statement's default delimiter is a space so you have to specify a comma for your CSV file. Since the `test` and `testRound` variables are decimals, they are not in quotes in the output. `testString` is character so it is in quotes.